# General solution of a mass spring system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

This is the differential equation that describes small amplitude vertical oscillations of a mass $m$ that is hanging from a spring
$$\frac{d^2x}{d t^{2}} + \frac{b}{m}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{k}{m} x = 0$$
Where $x$ is defined to be the displacement of the mass from equilibrium position, $b$ is the damping constant, $t$ is time and $k$ is the spring constant.

I want to find a general solution for the case in which small damping occurs.
I understand this to be when the damping constant $b^2 < 4\,\mathrm{km}$ but I am unsure how to go about finding a general solution. What type of mathematical tools would I need to find the solution and would these tools help me to find a general solution for if there was large damping or even critical damping?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda.html

Comment: Hi Ernie, I have seen that example on hyperphysics and although it does have an example of how to find the general solution, my equation is slightly different and I am unable to solve it even with the substitution method.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x$ by $A(e^{wt})$.

Thus your equation becomes:

$$
A(w^2)(e^{wt})+A(\frac{b}{m})(w)(e^{wt})+(\frac{k}{m})(A)(e^{wt})=0
$$

Simplifying:

$$
(w^2) + (\frac{b}{m})(w) + (\frac{k}{m})=0
$$

Find out the roots . Here you understand that  $(b^2)<=4km$ for real values of $w$.

Let the roots be $w_1$ and $w_2$

Finally your solution to the differential equation is:

**Case 1:** $w_1$ and $w_2$ are distinct:

$$x(t) = A (e^{w_1t})+B (e^{w_2t}) $$ where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants.

**Case 2:** $w_1$ and $w_2$ are identical:

$$x(t) = A (e^{w_1t}) + B t (e^{w_1t})$$ where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants.